# How to exit when task is finished in asyncio

Tags: python, task, python-asyncio, wait, telethon

In this shorted and simplified code I want to wait for all tasks to be completed( queue.join) and then leave.
This code open a network connection and download some data.
Unfortunately I have to push 'ctrl-c' because the 'client.run_until_disconnected()'.

The complete code works but I dont'know how to exit without keyboard interruption.
I have to schedule it with crontab so I can't use 'client.run_until_disconnected()'

EDIT : updated code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.7

import asyncio
import telethon
from telethon import TelegramClient
from telethon import functions, types
from datetime import datetime

api_id = 00000 # your api_id
api_hash = "your api hash"

async def worker(queue):
    while True:
        queue_book = await queue.get()
        book_name = queue_book.file.name
        print(book_name)
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        await client.download_media(queue_book,book_name)
        queue.task_done()

async def main():
    #Free ebook medical articles
    channel = await client(functions.messages.CheckChatInviteRequest('your channel hash'))
    #values message's id depend on the chosen channel
    ids = [63529,63528,63527,63526,63525,63524,63523,63522]
    queue = asyncio.Queue(1)
    workers = [asyncio.create_task(worker(queue)) for _ in range(5)]
    for booksId in ids:
        async for get_book in client.iter_messages(channel.chat, ids=booksId):
            await queue.put(get_book) 
    await queue.join()
    for the_worker in workers:
        the_worker.cancel()

async def wait_until(dt):
      now = datetime.now()
      await asyncio.sleep((dt - now).total_seconds())

async def run_at(dt, coro):
      await wait_until(dt)
      return await coro

client = TelegramClient("Test", api_id, api_hash)
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
client.start()

try:
    loop = loop.create_task(run_at(datetime(2021, 2, 19, 11,00),main()))    

    client.run_until_disconnected()
except KeyboardInterrupt as keyint:
    print("KeyboardInterrupt..")
    pass
```

Comment: What is `client`? Can you provide a runnable (but minimal) example that shows the issue?

Comment: Hi  , code updated. The code is runnable but you have to deal with the dependencies. When the workers are cancelled , the code wait for ctr-c . If I use "run_until_complete" it exits immediately because I use "await" ( that is what I understood reading the doc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`run_until_disconnected()` is just a helper function, you don't have an obligation to run it if you want to control when the event loop ends. The minimal change would be to replace `client.run_until_disconnected()` with `loop.run_forever()`, and call `loop.stop()` at the end of `main()`.

A more idiomatic approach would be to leave `main()` as it is, but instead of starting it with `create_task`, *await* it from your top-level coroutine (normally called `main` by convention, but you already chose that name for the other function). Then you can just call `asyncio.run(actual_main())`, and the program will automatically exit when `main` finishes. For example (untested):

```
# main and other functions as in the question

async def actual_main():
    global client
    client = TelegramClient("Test", api_id, api_hash)
    await client.start()
    await run_at(datetime(2021, 2, 19, 11, 00), main())

asyncio.run(actual_main())
```